# Windows Phone 8 : System.OutOfMemoryException when images are displayed in a longlistselector or pivot control

Tags: windows-phone-8

I searched a lot but not able to overcome the issue of "System.OutOfMemoryException" in windows phone 8 app... I basically capture images and store them in Isolated Storage and then allow user to browse them by initially listing in a longlistselector and then on tap showing the selected image using pivot control so that user can change the image by sliding... It works fine in emulator, I can capture as many image as I like and view them but on real device it starts throwing "System.OutOfMemoryException".... Please help me out... Thanx in advance...

Comment: can you show u code "storing the image in isolated storage"?

Comment: using (var local = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, store))
                    {
                        int bytes;
                        while ((bytes = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(contents, 0, contents.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            local.Write(contents, 0, bytes);
                        }
                        local.Dispose();
                    }


Above is the code....

Comment: But I believe storing is not the issue.. The problem occurs when I retrieve the images and try to display them in longlist or pivot control.....

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem. I noted that I always use "new" for creating bitmap container very much time, but I forget to release memory. Try fix that.

Comment: I can't get your point..If possible can you share your code showing what changes you actually made to make it work.. Thanks